# Getting unresolved carbon functions - mac qt 10.4 build

Tags: qt, macos, macos-carbon

Trying to compile some code that is primarily Qt, but has a bunch of calls into the the Carbon layer.

In Linking, all of the Carbon calls come up unresolved.

My config cmdline build has this: -sdk /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.4u.sdk -mmacosx-version-min=10.4 -carbon -universal

My project has this: CONFIG += i386 ppc, and
this:                QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -mmacosx-version-min=10.4

As you can see, I'm targeting/using the 10.4u sdk.

All of the Carbon calls come up unresolved.  Is there a way to specify the carbon libs directly on the link line?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to set this in Qmake, but linking to the Carbon framework is done via `-framework Carbon`, e.g.

```
g++ a.cpp -o a -framework Carbon
```

Since `-framework` is a linker option, you could try using it on Qmake’s equivalent of `LDFLAGS`. Alternatively, you could pass `-Wl,-framework,Carbon` to the compiler driver.

Comment: Specifying '-framework Carbon' in the QMAKE_LFLAGS var doesn't help - does show up on the linker command line.

Comment: @rickb Could you edit your question and paste the exact command line that’s being run, as well as the linker errors you’re getting?

Comment: Ok, I tee'd the link in to a commandfile and mucked around with it.  It's using g++ to do the link.  Adding the -Wl form of the arg worked in the commandline - I got a good link.  Now I have to get it specified properly in the QMake file.

Comment: @rickb Since you’re using `-Wl`, can’t you add it to `QMAKE_CXXFLAGS`?